# How to delete a pattern from a filename in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have files such as below and I want to cut `.resampled.wav` part

```
af_001_B.wav.resampled.wav
af_002_B.wav.resampled.wav
af_003_B.wav.resampled.wav
```

this would turn into

```
af_001_B.wav
af_002_B.wav
af_003_B.wav
```

Is there a simple command I can use to rename files in a directory?

Comment: Kindly add your efforts in form of code in your question. Its highly encouraged on SO to do so for OP to add their efforts in their questions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest write a for loop to rename those files

```
for file in $(ls); do prefix=${file%.resampled*}; mv $file $prefix; done
```

Brief:

1. Get filename
2. Remove suffix .resampled.wav
3. Rename file with new prefix

Good luck

Comment: Do not iterate the output of ls: `for file in *.resampled.wav; do [ "$file" = '*.resampled.wav' ] || mv -- "$file" "${file%.resampled.wav}"; done`